# Animate NSView constraints (layer backed view) on macOS objective-c

Tags: objective-c, constraints, core-animation, nsview

I am on XCode 12, macOS, objective-c, not iOS.

I have a menu (horizontal stack view) with 3 items:

[image]

The blue underline is created programmatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];     
    [self createAnimatedLineAtButton:self.importButton];
}

// Create line
- (void)createAnimatedLineAtButton:(NSButton*)button {

    // This view is layer backed
    SHViewCustomBackground* underlineView = [[SHViewCustomBackground alloc] init];
    
    underlineView.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorNamed:@"color_spot"]; // blue color
    underlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:underlineView];
    self.underlineView = underlineView;    

    [self updateAnimatedLineUnderButton:self.importButton];
}
```

The next codes updates the constraints (initially called on line creation above) and later on the click of each button.

```
- (void)updateAnimatedLineUnderButton:(NSButton *)button {
    
    // Constraints are stored here
    if (self.underlineConstraints) {
        [self.view removeConstraints:self.underlineConstraints];
    }

    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
        context.duration = 1;
        context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    
        NSView* underlineView = self.underlineView;
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(underlineView, button);
        self.underlineConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-[underlineView(1)]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil views:views];
        [self.view addConstraints:self.underlineConstraints];
    
        [self.view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
    } completionHandler:nil];    
}
```

Here are the button actions

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    
    [self updateAnimatedLineUnderButton:(NSButton*)sender];
}
```

Now my question: When i click buttons in this order "Import" > "Export" > "Import" the line animates as expected from Import to Export and back. Whenever i click on "Placeholder" (middle button) the line just jumps and doesn't animate. When i click on "Import" or "Export" afterwards it jumps too.

[image]

Im banging my head on whats wrong here. All buttons are connected correctly, all actions are triggered correctly.

EDIT: After comparing all buttons i discovered that both import and export button (where it works) have the same width.

Comment: I see the width of that underline also changes in the animation and note your comment about the widths. Maybe align to center and set width as two separate explicit  constraints (or even just give it a fixed width for now) and see how it goes?

Comment: it works with a fixed width. even align center constraint combined with "button-equalWidth" doesn't work. Whenever it comes to dynamic width it shows the behavior in the GIF. Unfortunately i want the dynamic width as its localized with different string lengths

Comment: Should work if you do the split animation - maybe update your code? Also maybe move the layoutSubtree to the completion block?

Comment: LayoutSubtree triggers the animation... can't therefor go to completion block. What do you mean by split animation?

Comment: I mean where you animate both the width and centre alignment constraints separately.

Comment: You are right I was thinking iOS and layoutSubviews ... anyhow I got it working, will post an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea ... it works. Initially I was going to do it your way but, you may not like this, ended up animated two constraints. But it works nicely.

[image]

The idea is very similar to yours but the difference here is that I create a leading and a trailing constraint and animate that in stead.

```
@implementation ViewController

- ( void ) viewDidLoad
{
    super.viewDidLoad;
    [self animateLine:self.longButton];
}

// Animate the line
- ( void ) animateLine:( NSButton * ) button
{
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup: ^ ( NSAnimationContext * context ) {

        context.duration = 1;
        context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
        self.leadingConstraint.animator.constant = button.frame.origin.x;
        self.trailingConstraint.animator.constant = self.stackView.bounds.size.width - button.frame.origin.x - button.frame.size.width;
        NSLog ( @"Setting leading to %f trailing to %f", self.leadingConstraint.constant, self.trailingConstraint.constant );

        self.lineField.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded;

    }];
}

- ( IBAction ) buttonAction:( id ) sender
{
    [self animateLine:sender];
}
```

This is it. The rest happens in storyboard. I set the constraints up so that the distances make sense by swapping the first and second item to taste.

Comment: This is great. Although I'd wanted to create everything in code and not in IB.

Comment: He he he you like to suffer ... I did as much as possible in storyboard just to save time and test the idea. This is also why I ended up doing it this way as it was the quickest. I think though that you can transfer this to code easily.

Comment: I will try to setup constraints on viewdidload and save them in some reference pointers. If this works i will definetely accept your answer as it is proofed to work. Thank you